# How to get input from web?

Tags: c++

i am trying to find out, how to get input from html inputs using c++. In windows you can send WM_GETTEXT to the window and it returns text, that you wanted. But is there any way to do the same thing in web interface?.

I am not interesting in sniffing packets now.

For example. Some site has html intput which expects name. I write name to the input. And then i want to catch it with my program

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you want to do, you have to set up a web server that calls your C++ application via [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface). So, you'll have an HTML page (static or generated by your program) that will contain a form, that refers to the URL of your application. So, when the user will click Submit, the browser will issue a request to the webserver, which in turn will call your application, passing to it the various POST/GET parameters related to the form.

Your application then can process the data, extracting such parameters from the environment variables (if the data is passed using the GET method) or from the standard input (if the POST method is used). To generate the output page (along with the output HTTP header) you'll simply have to write it to the standard output.

Comment: and if i would like to do it from existing page?

Comment: Wait, you're talking about intercepting the communication between the user on the local PC and any website?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I can think of (if you're using Linux) is using wget via system() from within your C++ app.

Wget to fetch the html page and output it to a file, parse the file for the URL of the form and data that it needs, pass the response as POST / GET via wget and so on.

That is, if I understood what you meant by "do it from existing page" correctly.